# How do I combine registration with clustering?

Tags: kinect, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the kinect and searching for one or more objects on a table. That works fine for me. Now I want to change the position of the kinect i.e. move it partly around the object and again search the objects lying on the table and then combine both object point clouds. The result of that should be that I get more point of an object (from different viewpoints) or in other word i will just remember the points I saw before. Is there a way to do that with pcl::registration? And do I have to use the registration algorithms before I cluster the objects or am I able to do it after clustering with only the few points I get from an object.

Thanks Stefan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10860/how-do-i-combine-registration-with-clustering?/) by [Stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/452/stefan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2011-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you should be able to do this with pcl registration. Check out the tutorial for ICP registration:
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/iterative_closest_point.php

I think the best initial approach would be to keep a downsampled combined pointcloud, and use ICP to register new clouds to the existing cloud, then add the new points to the combined cloud. Afterwards, you can use clustering ( http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cluster_extraction.php ) to separate the objects out.

---

Originally posted by [Helen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1033/helen/) with karma: 261 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/452/stefan/) on 2011-09-13**:
Thanks for the hint!